# How to make initializer list and class member initializer work together?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code neither compiles with -std=c++11 under gcc-4.7.1 nor clang-3.2.  So I think I did something wrong.  But I don't know why.  Can someone give me a hint?  Basically if I remove the in-class member initializer for X, it works.  So why doesn't initializer list work with in-class   member initializer?

```
struct X {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
};

int main() {
    X x = {1, 2};
}
```

gcc compile error:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:7:16: error: could not convert '{1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'X'
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, As I mentioned, yes.

Comment: Its those `= 1;` in the member decls that always make be double-take.

Comment: The thing is that when you have the initializers, it forms the equivalent of `X() : x{1}, y{1} {}`, which I'll bet is why aggregate initialization doesn't work.

Comment: @chris I was just thinking the same thing. A default constructor with a prebuilt initializer list would be the likely outcome when using such in-class initializers.

Comment: @chris you are right again. `X` is not an aggregate, as per 8.5.1. See edit to my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I was hoping to find a reference and you did :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By having the initialization of non-static data members at the point of declaration, your class is no longer an aggregate (see 8.5.1 Aggregates **[decl.init.aggr]**).

A workaround is to add a two-parameter constructor. This allows you to use initializer-list initialization, which allows same syntax as aggregate initialization, even if your class is not technically an aggregate.

```
struct X {
  X(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
};

int main() 
{
    X x1{1, 2};
    X x2 = {1,2};
}
```

**Note**: These rules have been relaxed for C++1y, meaning your type would indeed be an aggregate.

Comment: +1 for the reference. I suspected something like this but you beat me to the punch :p

Comment: "This allows you to use aggregate initialization" -- this is not entirely correct, what you're doing now is called *list-initialization*.

Comment: @Xeo, True. Same syntax, though :p

Comment: @Xeo I rephrased my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Alternately, could expected functionality be restored by explicitly declaring the default constructor (the new C++11 Foo() = default)? icando's case is unambiguous and clearly pod. So it's sad to see these two things being mutually exclusive, since the NSDMI values are really more just defaults if something more specific is not assigned.

Comment: @DwayneRobinson No, that wouldn't work. However, for C++14 these rules have been relaxed, so OP's type would actually be an aggregate. I may add a note on that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Looks like this is the one that will address the issue in the future: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html